Involution-symmetric idempotents of simple algebras
Is the following statement true?

A simple Artinian (simple finite-dimensional) $K$-algebra $A$ with involution has no symmetric (self-adjoint) primitive (minimal) idempotent if and only if $A$ is split and the involution is symplectic.

Every finite-dimensional simple algebra is central simple over its centre. One exercise in the book of involution is as follows: "Show that in a central simple algebra with involution, every left or right ideal is generated by a symmetric element, unless the algebra is split and the involution is symplectic."
This exercise shows one direction of the statement. Is the other direction also correct?
